# Damaged Superblock

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Jammy

I have a 512 GB USB stick that I use to keep my data on.  Unfortunately I had a bad habit of leaving it plugged in on reboots (I no longer do that).  But it resulted in a corrupt Superblock.

I dont care about the data as I have backups of it.  But I would like to get the use of the thumb drive back.  Even a reformat is fine but I'm unable to.  I want to wipe it clean and create a new partition and format it.

DISKS can see it but I can't do anything with it.
GPARTED doesn't even see the device.
LSBLK does show it listed as sdb
DD doesn't see it.
FSCK does identifies the Superblock error but I can't do anything else with any options
E2FSCK fails to restore from ANY of the backups.
TESTDISK was also ineffective on it.
SHRED works.   It manages to write the 1's and 0's without issue.

After all that, I'm still unable to make it even recognizable to the point I can even format it again. I would really like to be able to use this 512 GB thumb drive as it's fairly new.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `Disks`. Insert the drive then select the partition and click on the wheel icon. The first option is `Format Partition` Give it a volume name, select `Erase` and select the format type (default is usually FAT) Job done...

Comment: Inserting the drive does not present ANY icon for it.

Comment: Open `Disks` first... then insert the drive and select the USB drive from the left panel. The icons for drive actions will then be presented.

Comment: Error formatting disk - Error wiping device: Failed to probe the device '/dev/sdb' (udisks-error-quark, 0)

Comment: Personally then, I'd bin it. Always remove the drive safely to prevent corrupting it. Lesson learnt.

Comment: There should be a way to low level format it back to the factory settings.